# Compile .ejs files replacing variables

Tags: templates

I want to compile .ejs files, replacing variables and return a .ejs or .js file.

I have some files with extension .ejs, in the files I have some parts like 
`<%= autor.repo %>` and I want to replace this for the variables

How can I do it?

Comment: EJS-files are Javascript Template files, which would ideally render to HTML. You need to tie a JSON-file with that EJS-file.

Answer (score 0):

Using the renderFiles option :)

```
var data = ejs.renderFile('../route/route.ejs',{

autor:{
    name: "Eric"
}

},function(err,data){
     if(err){
              console.log(err)
     } 
     else{
       return data
     }
  });
```

Next, using fs module to create a new archive :)

```
    fs.writeFile('newName.ejs', data, (err) => {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('It\'s saved!');
    });
```